# Light bouncing (Unity)

Tags: light, unity

I am trying to make a cube/cuboid emit light. Now I am succesful in making it luminous (lighting up without the help of other lights), but it is not lighting up other things.

[image: Mettaton]

I have noticed switching the render engine to Cycles instead of Eevee fixes the problem, but the other problem is I am not trying to render it, but import it to Unity, which is not for rendering.

Also, rendering it Unity provides no color:

[image]

What should I do to make it light other things?

<sup>btw yes, i am making mettaton from undertale</sup>

Comment: First of all you are correct that eevee and cycles will give you different results. Cycles with 0 settings from you will do most of the work for you and it will look good but Eevee is realtime render and as such it has lower performance with shadows and light... such as this is normal and if you want to see light glowing you can only check "BLOOM" in render settings... If you want to see it in Unity, did you already tried to export it to unity and see if it works or not? because this is simply Eevee real time render issue

Comment: @MikoCG I have tried to import it into Unity and it is not colouring any of the emmiting parts.